# How do I sub-sort a view?

Tags: views

We have a view containing two fields that we would like to sort - specifically issue # and Title. We would like to sort the view first by the Issue # field and then secondly by Title, so that nodes from the same issue are clustered and sorted again by title.

How can we sub-sort a view so that one field is the primary sort and another is the secondary sort (similar to sorting in a spreadsheet)?

Comment: Just add two entries in the "Sort criteria" section? Or that's not what you want?

Comment: Yes. I was looking at the table settings. Thanks :-)

Comment: Add that as an answer, and I will up vote it.

Comment: No need to upvote, as I hardly put any effort in it, but marking answer as accepted will remove your question from all "unanswered" lists on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add two entries in the "Sort criteria" section, left column, bottom. The more important sorting criteria should be on top.

[image]

Add button can be used as a drop-down, to show Rearrange button, if needed.